# SQL Server Database Changes to Customer

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've seen a lot of software that does something similar to what we need but I wanted to get specific to make sure I'm not barking up the wrong tree.

We have a C#/WPF/Silverlight application in beta form that has updates weekly for testing and debugging by remote users. I have created a simple routine that updates the customer with out a problem.

We are at the point where we are having to make database changes regularly to add new features.  We are using the database project and creates a deployment script.

I tried writing a program that implements this script and failed miserably.

How do we migrate the database changes from our dev db to our customer's db with our updates without having to jump through a bunch of hoops?

I hope this makes since, desperately need a good solution that requires little input from the customer since they will be clueless how it works. Right now, they click one button and it updates.

Comment: Right now how the script are setup so that customers are using as `just click one button and it updates` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here at Red Gate we've got a tool called [SQL Packager](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-packager/), which takes a script and turns it into an exe that the customer can run. Is this something that might work for you?

Comment: ahh didn't know that Red Gate did that, I guess I didn't read it closely enough.

Comment: We have downloaded the trial. It looks like exactly what we need! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Glad it's of use. If you have any feedback on this tool, please let us know as we're always looking to improve how database changes are deployed.

Answer (score 1):

We use a database diff tool called SQL Effects Clarity to show the differences in Stored Proces/Tables, etc.

Then we just go through the differences and make the changes to the structure, and then import the data changes.

Doing the update manually will save you time in the long run because you will find small differences all over the database that need to be updated.  You'll end up finding bugs before you release it, and you'll be glad you did.

Comment: This defeats our purpose since we have quite a few customers databases that use this and update regularly. Doing anything manually is what we are trying to avoid...